# Visual Studio Code debug mode - Flutter & Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, debugging

I'm stuck in debug mode, need help.

Previously, when I came to the page in debug mode, I could easily fix problems by *stopping where I marked*. But recently when I'm in `debug mode`, it **doesn't stop where I marked**. When the page is opened, the `debug mode` works, but when I scroll with `f10`, it goes into the `framework.dart` file and **continues from there** and by no means stops where I want it. Is there a setting for this?